# command not ended prperly. how to fix this error

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert, command

```
SELECT * INTO NMANDEV.EMANADM.UCFM_JOB_INSTANCE_DATA_LOG
FROM NMANSTG.EMANADM.UCFM_JOB_INSTANCE_DATA_LOG
```

Comment: I believe this is what you're trying to write,
`SELECT * FROM NMANSTG.EMANADM.UCFM_JOB_INSTANCE_DATA_LOG`

Comment: Are you trying to copy data from one table to another? That would be `insert ... select`. Hard to be sure what you need though.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Who knows ... what do you want to do, exactly? Looks like you're trying to "copy" data from one table to another. If that's so, then you'd

```
INSERT INTO NMANDEV.EMANADM.UCFM_JOB_INSTANCE_DATA_LOG
   SELECT *
     FROM NMANSTG.EMANADM.UCFM_JOB_INSTANCE_DATA_LOG
```

However, that's wrong as well because what are `NMANDEV`, `EMANADM` and `NMANSTG`? `UCFM_JOB_INSTANCE_DATA_LOG` seems to be a table name.

Generally speaking, if tables belong to different users in the same database, you'd just precede table names with their owners, e.g.

```
insert into NMANDEV.UCFM_JOB_INSTANCE_DATA_LOG
select * from NMANSTG.UCFM_JOB_INSTANCE_DATA_LOG
```

(where `NMANDEV` is one user, while `NMANSTG` is another).